# Formula for finding area for all polygons

Tags: polygons

I have a image below, kinda hard to see but was wondering if anyone has seen this formula and what its from and how to use it.

thx

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_iy_{i+1}-x_{i+1}y_i)$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: The resolution of that image is *terrible*!  In any case, you should never rely on images here when text/MathJax would suffice (*except for specific geometric shapes to get ideas across*).  Visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: Could be helpful: [MSE: Area of an irregular polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492407/area-of-an-irregular-polygon/492503#492503).