# What is the expected value of the area of a triangle inside a triangle?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, expected-value

One random point is chosen randomly from each of the sides of a triangle with an area A. These lines are connected to be a new triangle inside of the original triangle. Calculate the expected area of the new triangle.

I don't even know how to start thinking this problem. If I choose the random variable to be $X= \text{Area of the new triangle}$, can I assume it to be uniformly distributed?

Update: The answer is given and it is supposed to be $\frac{1}{4}A.$

Comment: So you don't know anything about the original triangle, other than its area?

Comment: @T_M Unfortunately, only the area is given.

Comment: You can apply an affine transformation on the triangle to send it to an equilateral triangle or right-isosceles triangle, depending on how you wanna solve it.

Comment: WLOG, the vertices are $(0,0), (2,0), (c,A)$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Um...what is $h$ in the answer supposed to be?

Comment: @JohnHughes Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @SharkyKesa's hint, observe that if you apply a linear transformation to your triangle (and the three selected points), the **ratio** between the area of the subtriangle and the main triangle remains invariant. So you can begin by transforming the main triangle to any one that's convenient to work with. I propose one with vertices $A = (0,0), B = (1, 0), C = (0, 1)$, whose area is $T = \frac12$.

Picking vertices for the subtriangle in each edge in turn gives
$$
v_1 = (0, t)\\
v_2 = (u, 0)\\
v_3 = (1-s, s).
$$
where $s,t,u$ are uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$.

Note that $v_1v_2v_3$ is a counterclockwise traversal of the triangle.

Following the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492407/area-of-an-irregular-polygon), the area of the triangle $v_1v_2v_3$ is
\begin{align}
S 
&= \frac12\left(-ut + us + (1-s)t \right)\\
2S&= u(s-t) + t - st\\
\end{align}
To compute the expected value of $2S$, we integrate over $[0, 1]^3$ to get
\begin{align}
avg(2S)
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 u(s-t) + t - st ~du ~dt ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left. (\frac{u^2}{2}(s-t) + u(t - st)) \right|_{u=0}^1  ~dt ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}(s-t) + (t - st)   ~dt ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}s + \frac12 t  - st   ~dt ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1 \left. \frac{1}{2}st + \frac12 \frac{t^2}{2}  - s\frac{t^2}{2} \right|_{t=0}^1  ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}s + \frac14   - \frac{s}{2}  ~ds\\
&= \int_0^1  \frac14~ds\\
&= \frac14
\end{align}
so that the average of $S$ is $\frac{1}{8}$, which is $\frac{1}{4}T$, where $T = \frac12$ is the area of the original outer triangle $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might start thinking about the problem.

Suppose that the original triangle has vertices at $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be uniform $[0,1]$ random variables. Then the new triangle has vertices at points

$(U x_1 + (1-U)x_2, Uy_1 + (1-U)y_2)$, $(V x_2 + (1-V)x_3, Vy_2 + (1-V)y_3)$ and $(W x_3 + (1-W)x_1, Wy_3 + (1-W)y_1)$. Can you see what I've done here? Do you know a way to work out the area of a triangle from just the coordinates of it's vertices?

Comment: This means you're using random barycentric coordinates, relative to the given triangle, seen as an affine basis of the plane.

Comment: Consider applying @SharkyKesa's comment to choose wise locations for the three vertices.